# generate traffic at wire speed

Tags: linux, networking, testing

I have x86 based machine with Intel Core2 CPU 6300 1.86GHz and 2G of
memory. I'm looking for options to generate traffic on the machine at line
rate, or as close as possible.

OS is Fedora 20 with with stock kernel 3.17.4-200.

For network cards I have a few choices:

Broadcom NetXtreme BCM5754 1Gb PCIe

For traffic generation I found a few tools:

```
- netperf
- iperf
- PF_RING (looks like it's quite new and will require to load a new
kernel module)
```

I would appreciate if someone could share his/her experience and would
recommend which tool fits better to generate a traffic at wire speed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with the others, but I can tell you that I've kept a 4-port GigE Intel server NIC card completely busy with `iperf3`.

If you're not getting to within about 90% of line speed with `iperf3`, I'd say that's a pretty good indicator that you've got a bottleneck, and that it's somewhere *other* than in `iperf3`.

Comment: thanks for comment. What is the difference between iperf and iperf3? (I see the both in yum repository)

Comment: @Mark: The protocols are different, so you can't mix the two. There are [feature differences](http://software.es.net/iperf/) between the two versions as well.